Why Can't I Derive the Specific Solution $x(t) = t^m$ from the General Solution of $t^2 x'' - 6x = 0$
I was trying to determine the values of the parameter $m$ for which $x(t) = t^m$ is a solution to the differential equation $t^2  x'' - 6x = 0$.
I successfully found these values by calculating the second derivative of the proposed solution:
$x''(t) = m(m-1)t^{m-2}$
and substituting both the solution and its derivative into the DE:
$t^2 m(m-1)t^{m-2} - 6t^m=0$
and solving the equation for $m$ yields the roots $m_1$ and $m_2$:
$m^2-m-6=0$
$m_1 = 3 , m_2 = -2$
However, when I attempted to solve the provided differential equation to find its general solution, I arrived at an expression from which I could not directly recover the specific solution by simply defining the integration constants. Below is my solution process:
$t^2  x'' - 6x = 0$
$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{1}{x}= 6t^{-2}$
$\frac{d}{dt}\int\frac{dx}{x}=6\int{t^{-2}}\,dt$
$\frac{d}{dt}\ln{x}=\frac{-6}{t}+C_1$
$\int{d\ln{x}} = -6\int{\frac{dt}{t}}+C_1\int{dt}$
$\ln{x}=-6\ln{t}+C_1t+C_2=-ln{t^6}+\ln{e^{C_1t}}+\ln{e^{C_1}}=\ln{\frac{e^{C_1t+C_2}}{t^6}}$
$x= \frac{e^{C_1t+C_2}}{t^6}$
I am confused because the general solution I derived does not appear to directly include the suggested solution $x(t) = t^{m}$. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help clarify this discrepancy or help me identify any issues in the solution process.
Cheers!

The equation is not separable, the left hand side in line 2 is not the derivative with respect to t of something.

I agree with @Paul.  The general solution of $t^2 x'' - 6x = 0$ turns out to be $y =  C_1 t^{-2}+C_2 t^3$.

This now makes perfect sense to me. Thank you so much, truly appreciate your help!

This is an Euler differential equation, solving the indicial equation $\lambda^2 -\lambda -6 = 0$ gives $\lambda_1 = 3$, $\lambda_2 = -2$. And thus the general solution is of form $y = c_1t^{-2} + c_2t^3$ as stated by GEdgar in the comments. What is Euler DE? How do we get this indicial equation and how do we know that the solution will take this form?
Euler DE is of the following form:
$$t^nx^{(n)} + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}x^{(n-1)}+\dots+a_1tx' + a_0x = b(t),\quad\text{($a_i$ are constants)}$$
Notice that assuming $t>0$ and putting $s=\log{t}$. Our differential equation is transformed into a simple second-order ODE with constant coefficients.
For such differential equation, we have a general theorem in ODEs that the solution will be of the form $$x(t) = \sum_{k=1}^mp_k(t)e^{\lambda_kt}$$ here we have $\lambda_1, \dots\lambda_m$ zeroes of char. poly. $n_1...n_m$ their multiplicity and arbitrary poly of degree $\le$ $n_k-1$. Now we consider our substitution we get the following $$x(t) = \sum_{k=1}^mp_k(s)e^{\lambda_ks} = \sum_{k=1}^mp_k(\log{t})t^{\lambda_k}.$$
As you see this is exactly the form of the solution. Since the roots are distinct the polynomial is just a constant and hence the solution is just $y = c_1t^{-2} + c_2t^3$. Now the indicial equation equation comes from the substitution, try and see. The theorem I mentioned is not too hard to prove either.
